# Getting android attachments from mail with imaplib

Tags: android, python, imap

I can read attachments sent from all email clients I've tested except for androids default email app. It works through the gmail app in android though.

Here's some of the code:

```
import email as emaillib

result, data = imap_conn.uid('fetch', email_id, '(RFC822)')
raw_email = data[0][1]

get_attachments(emaillib.message_from_string(raw_email))

def get_attachments(email_message_instance):
    attachments = []
    for part in email_message_instance.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue

        data = part.get_payload(decode=True)
        if not data:
            continue
        filename = part.get_filename()

        print 'appending attachment with filename: ', filename
        attachments.append((filename, data))

    return attachments
```

When I send one attachment from the default email app in android it prints:

```
appending attachment with filename: None
appending attachment with filename: None
appending attachment with filename: =?utf-8?B?SU1BRzAxOTMuanBn?=
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved the problem, It seems my android default mail app writes content disposition for everything.

And the file name was all wicked as well.

So I solved the problem with (Since I'm only interested in media attachments):

```
from email.header import decode_header
    def get_attachments(email_message_instance):
        attachments = []
        for part in email_message_instance.walk():

            if part.get_content_maintype() not in ['image', 'video', 'audio']:
                continue

            if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
                continue

            data = part.get_payload(decode=True)
            if not data:
                continue

            filename = part.get_filename()      
            filename =  u' '.join(w.decode(e or 'ascii') for w,e in decode_header(filename))        
            attachments.append((filename, data))

        return attachments
```